# Help needed to identify late 1960s or 1970s book about witches

Tags: story-identification, novel, witches

I need help trying to remember the title of a book I read in the late 1970s (likely published in the 1970s or late 1960s that was about a conflict between a good witch and a bad warlock.

The bad warlock could manifest as a car with headlights that were like his spectacles. On at least one occasion, the good witch escapes because the warlock could not pursue her across moving water in his non-human form.

Answer (score 4):

I think this could be John Bellairs' [The House With a Clock In Its Walls](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/295801.The_House_with_a_Clock_in_Its_Walls). There's an evil ghost with distinctive spectacles, a good witch, and a car chase with bright headlights. I don't specifically recall characters comparing the headlights to the spectacles, or running water mattering, but it's at least worth a look as a possibility.

[This web page](https://impossible.home.blog/2019/10/31/the-house-with-the-clock-in-its-walls-by-john-bellairs/) shows some of the illustrations, which might jog your memory to confirm or deny.

Comment: When the car is chasing Lewis, Jonathan and Mrs. Zimmerman they get away because the car cannot drive along a bridge over a stream.